# Yii2 datetimepicker select dates starting from 12 hours after today's date

Tags: php, yii2, widget, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker widget in my code and i'd like to allow the selectable dates to start from 12hours after today's date. How can I do that please?

```
<?php echo DateTimePicker::widget([
            'model'=>$model,
        'attribute' => 'start_time',
//        'attribute' => 'a_start_date',
        'name'=>'start_time',
        'type' => DateTimePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_PREPEND,
        'options' => ['placeholder'=> 'Enter start time...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            //'format' => 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:ii'
            'format' => 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii:00',
            'weekStart'=>1,
            'startDate' => "+1d",


        ]
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: [This might be the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47044767/3787519)

Comment: @InsaneSkull I already found this but unfortunately did not help :(

Comment: [Combine this answer with above suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386308/add-x-number-of-hours-to-date/17942233).  I can post answer but will take few hours.

Comment: For idea `'startDate' =>  date(dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii:ss", strtotime('+12hours'))` do something like this with your preferred datetime format

Comment: @InsaneSkull Yes I tried this but it completely ignores and doesn't read this logic

Comment: Is it kartik datetimepicker?

Comment: @InsaneSkull Yes it is